# Como saber si un ResultSet contiene Null en columna?

Tags: java

Trato de formular una condición la cual sea si mi columna `x` contiene `Null` me mande un mensaje, si no es así que me llene un *excel*. tengo lago de este estilo, Gracias!!.

```
if (res.next()) {
    while (res.next()) {
        Row filaDatos = sheet.createRow(numfilaDatos);
        for (int a = 0; a < numCol; a++) {
            Cell celdaDatos = filaDatos.createCell(a);
            celdaDatos.setCellValue(res.getString(a + 1));
        }
        numfilaDatos++;
    }
    fileOut = new FileOutputStream("Solicitud_R3.xlsx");
    book.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Archivo de Solicitud Generado");

} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Existen Faltantes de R3");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al obtener el [**ResultSet**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) puedes usar el método [**wasNull()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()) para realizar esta validación:

```
   if (rs.wasNull()) {
        //Contiene valor null
    }
```

> [**wasNull()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull())  Informa si la última lectura de columna tenía un
>   valor de SQL NULL. Tenga en cuenta que primero debe llamar a uno de
>   los métodos getter en una columna para tratar de leer su valor y luego
>   llamar al método wasNull para ver si el valor leído era SQL NULL